# Dataframe convert float to string with all decimal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

by reading excel with pandas trying to convert floats to string with all decimal points

```
df = pd.read_excel('data/DHTest.xlsx',  keep_default_na=False, na_filter=False, dtype=str)
```

input in excel -0.00001 results to output in parquet  -1e-05

--

if I try to run without dtype=str

```
df = pd.read_excel('data/DHTest.xlsx',  keep_default_na=False, na_filter=False, dtype=str)
```

results from -0.00001 to -0.00001 but by converting to string `df = df.astype('string')` creates again -1e-05

I need to write parquet with all columns as string `df.to_parquet('data/DHTest.parquet')` with output -0.00001 and not -1e-05

Comment: ```df['column'].map('{:,.6f}'.format)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
#Dummy Data
l = [0.0000001,0.00000002]
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=["data"])
-->
           data
0  1.000000e-07
1  2.000000e-08

#Transform (fixed number of zeros)
df["data"] = df["data"].map('{:,.8f}'.format)
-->
          data
0  0.00000010
1  0.00000002

#Transform (max number of zeros, but remove trailing)
df["data"] = df["data"].apply(lambda x: ('{:,.8f}'.format(x)).rstrip("0"))
-->
         data
0   0.0000001
1  0.00000002
```

Comment: I have input 0.1 to 0.00001.  df["data"].map('{:,.8f}'.format) will create 0.10000000 and 0.0000100. Is there a way to keep output without additional 0?

Comment: I included a version, that removes trailing zeros